# python regex doesn't match as expected (and as pythex.org does)

Tags: python, regex

I am using Python 3.4.2, 2.7.9 and also the online tester at http://pythex.org and get different results on the same input. In the following I am trying to match a word delimited by either "|" or end of string.

```
for w in ['OR', 'ELSE', 'WHAT']:
   m=re.match(r'(^|\|)(%s)($|\|)'%w,r'OR|ELSE|WHAT')
   if m:
      print(m.group())

m=re.match(r'(^|\|)(ELSE)(\||$)',r'OR|ELSE|WHAT')
   if m:
      print(m.group())
```

Run locally I get only

```
 OR|
```

as a result while on pythex I get the expected matches on all words (http://bit.ly/1vmIAjX). I've had some inconsistencies with having to use for example `.*WORD.*` instead of just `WORD` before.

Is there something that I have to include? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just turn the unwanted groups to non-capturing groups and print the capturing group index number, so that it won't include the preceding or following character. And i suggest you to use `re.search` function instead of `re.match`, since `re.match` must try to match from the begining of the string.

```
>>> m=re.search(r'(?:^|\|)(ELSE)(?:\||$)',r'OR|ELSE|WHAT')
>>> if m:
    print(m.group(1))


ELSE
>>> re.search(r'(^|\|)(ELSE)(\||$)',r'OR|ELSE|WHAT').group()
'|ELSE|'
```

Your code,

```
>>> for w in ['OR', 'ELSE', 'WHAT']:
        m=re.match(r'(^|\|)(%s)($|\|)'%w,r'OR|ELSE|WHAT')
        if m:
            print(m.group())


OR|
```

Why the above code displays `OR|` only is mainly because of `re.match` function. It tries to match from the beginning of the string, so it checks for `^` , start of the line or `|` at the start. From the words present in the given list, it would match the `OR` only because it's at the beginning , and also it matches the following `|` symbol.

```
>>> for w in ['OR', 'ELSE', 'WHAT']:
        m=re.search(r'(^|\|)(%s)($|\|)'%w,r'OR|ELSE|WHAT')
        if m:
            print(m.group())


OR|
|ELSE|
|WHAT
```